# Does Eclipse Equinox OSGi implementation implement osgi.serviceloader? At what version?

Tags: osgi, equinox, aries

I am in a situation where I could use the SPI service loader in OSGi environment. I found out about `osgi.serviceloader.registrar`. However, what is unclear to me is whether this is supported by Equinox OOTB or if I still need [Apache Aries SPI Fly](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html) to have it implemented and usable?